# Error installing Adobe Flash Catalyst Panini

Tags: windows-7, installation, flash, installer

I have installed Flash Catalyst Panini (a preview release) on one machine (Windows 7 x64, latest updates) with no problem.  On another system with the same setup I get the following in the install error log; it seems to bug out when installing the MS VC++ runtimes (at least that is the component I see being installed before the error).

```
Exit Code: 7
-------------------------------------- Summary --------------------------------------
 - 0 fatal error(s), 24 error(s), 26 warning(s)
WARNING: Payload {40F95A03-885A-45fb-9A14-486BEFEDDF34} Adobe Flash Player 10 Plugin is already installed and the session payload {00C5CA45-DFBA-4ceb-9DF2-E932233CCF68} Adobe Flash Player 10 Plugin has no upgrage/conflict relationship with it.
WARNING: Payload {7E5AA19B-0B85-4f44-BA26-728851489200} Adobe Flash Player 10 ActiveX is already installed and the session payload {B65AD0E3-C64A-4b91-BAEF-0EA667697FB1} Adobe Flash Player 10 ActiveX has no upgrage/conflict relationship with it.
WARNING: OS requirements not met for {24AA97EB-F636-4018-9324-48540C69CF3D}
WARNING: OS requirements not met for {694213D7-1E0E-4C8F-B822-E2E3680C0FCE}
WARNING: Warning: {2F6B67F4-A2BB-45D7-A80C-25FF646CC1C5} Adobe Player for Embedding will not be repaired, due to updated patch of STI and one of the top level payload is being installed.
WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure
WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure
WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure
WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure
WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure
WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure
WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure
WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure
WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure
WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure
WARNING: Warning: {2F6B67F4-A2BB-45D7-A80C-25FF646CC1C5} Adobe Player for Embedding will not be repaired, due to updated patch of STI and one of the top level payload is being installed.
WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure
WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure
WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure
WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure
WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure
WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure
WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure
WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure
WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure
WARNING: Payload cannot be installed due to dependent operation failure
ERROR: Verifying payload integerity : Failed with code 1
ERROR: MsiConfigureProductEx failed with error: 1612
ERROR: The following payload errors were found during install:
ERROR:  - Adobe Flash Player 10 Plugin: Install failed
ERROR:  - Microsoft_VC90_ATL_x86: Install failed
ERROR:  - Adobe Media Player: Install failed
ERROR:  - Microsoft_VC90_CRT_x86: Install failed
ERROR:  - Microsoft_VC80_ATL_x86: Install failed
ERROR:  - Adobe Flash Catalyst Panini: Install failed
ERROR:  - AdobeHelp: Install failed
ERROR:  - Microsoft_VC90_MFC_x86: Install failed
ERROR:  - Adobe Media Encoder CS5 X64: Install failed
ERROR:  - AdobeTypeSupport CS5: Install failed
ERROR:  - Adobe Flash Fonts1: Install failed
ERROR:  - Microsoft_VC90_ATL_x86_x64: Install failed
ERROR:  - Microsoft_VC90_CRT_x86_x64: Install failed
ERROR:  - Microsoft_VC80_CRT_x86: Install failed
ERROR:  - Microsoft_VC90_MFC_x86_x64: Install failed
ERROR:  - DynamiclinkSupport: Install failed
ERROR:  - Adobe Flash Player 10 ActiveX: Install failed
ERROR:  - AdobeCMaps CS5: Install failed
ERROR:  - Microsoft_VC80_MFC_x86: Install failed
ERROR:  - Microsoft_VC80_MFCLOC_x86: Install failed
ERROR:  - Adobe AIR: Install failed
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The install log is not detailed enough for me to figure out *exactly* where the problem is coming from.  I was able to download all the required MSVC runtimes from Microsoft and install them manually.  Adobe is installing the runtime DLL's manually; each package has a manifest file in its folder.

Are there any command line switches for there installer that could provide more verbose output?  I have also considered editing the installer XML to skip the MSVC package installs, but that would probably be overkill.

Adobe does not have any forum specific to this preview release from what I can tell, otherwise I would asking there.  Has anyone experienced the same or similar problem and managed to solve it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this problem was affecting a lot of people.

Here are some solutions provided by Adobe themselves:

1. http://forums.adobe.com/thread/742895
2. h**p://kb2.adobe.com/cps/842/cpsid_84252.html
3. h**p://kb2.adobe.com/community/publishing/880/cpsid_88008.html

Case closed on my end.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: uninstall every component mentioned in the log (e.g. Flash Player, AIR, Visual C runtimes) then install again. Looks as if it might be versioning problem that the installer can't figure out.